# Which syntax highlighter does Firefox Quantum Dev Tools use?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, firefox-developer-tools

Does anyone know what kind of syntax highlighter (and what theme, if it has any) does Firefox Quantum (v57+) use in it's **Inspector** panel of their developer tools?

I believe it was introduced with their new Photon UI, but I'm not sure whether it's just an updated code coloring theme or a totally new coloring processor.

Their blog article:
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/09/developer-edition-devtools-update-now-with-photon-ui/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the general tree view within the Firefox DevTools Inspector is developed by Mozilla. Though the editor used when editing a node (context menu > *Edit As HTML*) [is CodeMirror](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/574f4f58fe09dd590ea892406e237318c31705b4/devtools/client/inspector/markup/markup.xhtml), which is also used in other parts of the DevTools like the Debugger.

The theme is self-created to fit to the [Photon layout](http://design.firefox.com/photon/welcome.html).